# How to download 10 newest files of type CSV via SFTP using WinSCP?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I use WinSCP quite basically from C#. For example I know that I can download several CSV files from an FTP site using this code:

```
var remotePath = "some\path*.csv";
var localPath = "some\path";
TransferOperationResult transferResult =
    session.GetFiles(remotePath, localPath, false, transferOptions);
```

But that downloads all the CSVs from the SFTP site. I only want the latest 10. I see from this link: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file how to get the latest file. And I have found using intellisense that there is a `RemoteFileInfoCollection` class.

But this class isn't very well documented (or at least not well enough for me to use)

Questions:

1. How can I use this class?
2. How can I request 'some' of the CSVs on an SFTP site using `seesion.GetFiles()`, since the `remotePath` param is a string and not a list. I know that I could loop through a list of paths and download those from the FTP, is that a reasonable approach? I'm not sure I'd want to call `GetFiles()` multiple times considering that it seems to specifically be named as file(s), and I know that it does download multiple files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code [you have found to download the one latest file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#csharp) and just replace `FirstOrDefault` with [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) and iterate the set to download all selected files.

I'm also using [`EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) instead of `ListDirectory`, as it can filter files by filemask on its own.

```csharp
const string remotePath = "/remote/path";
const string localPath = "C:\local\path";

IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo> files =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(remotePath, "*.csv", EnumerationOptions.None)
    .Where(file => !file.IsDirectory)
    .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
    .Take(10);

string destPath = Path.Combine(localPath, "*");
foreach (RemoteFileInfo file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading {0}...", file.Name);
    session.GetFiles(RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(file.FullName), destPath).Check();
}
```